# how to make auto increment and restart from 1 again by first day of date?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, auto-increment

I want make auto increment by using php but when date start from 01 or my table is empty it's number restart to 1 again 
this is my number :

```
$day = date('t');
$month = date('n');
$years = date('Y');
$num = 001/$month/$years
```

and I was convert a number

```
$cut = (int)substr($num,2,1);
```

and then I dont know how to increase the number and go back to 1 again when date start from 01

thankyou for answering and spent your time for answer my newbie post

Comment: Why would you `001` instead of `1`? Decimal numbers don't have leading `0`.

Comment: This sounds like a very bad idea. Can you explain why you think you need to do this please.

Comment: Please use DateTime to work with dates in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: but i have to appear '00' in my number ,
actually this is my homework and i cant solve this , i was tried searching in google but i cant found it.
if i use date time i cant add a string in like 'XII' 
i need to change a month to roman number , but i was solved that

Comment: now my problem is how to auto increment a number and start from 1 again when date start from 01 , im really frustated , please helpp

Comment: I think you should do a `var_dump($num);` it's probably not what you think it is

Comment: thanks everyone , i have solved my problem , i just add 1 field in my table called month_and_years . and input it with current month and years , then i loop that with while and set WHERE current month and years = month_and_years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PHP `explode` :-

```
<?php
$num = '001/$month/$years';
$num=explode("/",$num);
$cut = (int)$num[0];
echo ++$cut;
?>
```

Comment: can it works with auto increment when '00' is in a number ?
and can you give me an example how to auto increment this number ? thankyou for answering

Comment: use **++$cut** for increment @JeremyHermawan

Comment: sorry,i mean how to auto increment this number and going back to 1 again when date is 01 ,
thankss

Comment: sorry @JeremyHermawan i am not understand what you actual want :(

Comment: umm , let me explain ,
so i want to make a number of delivery order , and every time i make delivery order , a number will increase by 1 until day 01 of the next month.
when  day is 01 in next month , the number will restart from 1 again

sorry for my bad english , lol